# Intuition behind inequality for angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I've been going through my lecture notes and whilst revising angular momentum operators I came across the following inequality. I can't quite figure out why the inequality is this way round, surely if we want the norms to be non negative, we need the inequalities to be the other way around? (The lecture notes are correct as they reach the correct conclusion using these two inequalities)

So they have calculated the norms of the lowered and raised wavefunctions:

$||J_-ψ||^2 = (λ − m^2 + m)^2||ψ|^2$ and $||J_+ψ||^2 = (λ − m^2 - m)^2||ψ|^2$ and from here they have concluded that as the norms cannot be negative we must have:

$λ ≥ m(m − 1)$ and equality implies $J_−ψ = 0$
and
$λ ≥ m(m + 1)$ and equality implies $J_+ψ = 0$

Comment: Can you include text instead of the image? Having text makes it easier for people on different devices to read it easily, and also helps search engines to index this page.

Comment: Sure no problem, sorry about that!